# Puzzling eigenvector degeneracy

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

This seems like it should be simple, but it's driving me crazy so if I embarrass myself, well, it won't be the first time.

The matrix

$\left(  \begin{array}{cc}0 & -1 \\ 1 & 2\end{array}\right)$

has a single degenerate eigenvalue $\lambda=1$, unless I really messed up a simple calculation.  I am expecting two eigenvectors, but when I solve for the eigenvectors $(a,b)$ I get the equation $a=-b$.  This bothers me because once $a$ (or $b$) is selected, there is no freedom in selecting $b$ (or $a$).  Therefore, $a=-b$ and, apart from magnitude, there is only one eigenvector.  Shouldn't there be two?  Where am I going wrong?

Comment: I’m going to pick on your terminology a little, because it has the potential of leading you into errors later. This matrix does *not* have “only one eigenvector.” As you’ve determined, *every* non-zero vector of the form $(a,-a)^T$ is an eigenvector. However, the space spanned by these vectors is only one-dimensional, which is OK, It just means that the matrix isn’t diagonalizable, as Ian explains below.

Comment: @amd Thanks.  That's what I tried to indicate when I said "apart from magnitude".

Comment: @bob.sacamento It was close, except there is also "apart from sign" (or in general "complex sign", where a "complex sign" is a $z \in \mathbb{C}$ with $|z|=1$.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some matrices are not diagonalizable. In these cases they have an eigenvalue with an "algebraic multiplicity", say $a$, and a "geometric multiplicity" say $g$ with $g<a$. The algebraic multiplicity is the multiplicity of the associated root of the characteristic polynomial; the geometric multiplicity is the number of linearly independent eigenvectors for the eigenvalue. The only thing that holds in general is $1 \leq g \leq a$, but $g$ could be any integer in that range.

In this particular case the matrix has a single eigenvalue with $a=2,g=1$, so your results are correct.

Comment: Thanks! Apart from going through the exercise of finding the eigenvectors, is there a way to tell if a matrix is diagonalizable?

Comment: @bob.sacamento Generally no, although there are many sufficient conditions for diagonalizability which come up in certain situations. For example, all "normal" matrices, i.e. those real matrices satisfying $A A^T = A^T A$, are diagonalizable (albeit in general over $\mathbb{C}$, not $\mathbb{R}$). In the $2 \times 2$ case the situation is pretty simple: a non-diagonal matrix is diagonalizable if and only if $T^2 \neq 4 \Delta$ where $T$ is the trace and $\Delta$ is the determinant. But there is no such simple criterion in higher dimensions.

Comment: What are the odds that I could put some four numbers into a 2x2 and get a non-diagonalizable matrix?  I came up with this matrix just because I was wanting an example with degenerate eigenvalues.  I am surprised that it turns out to be non-diagonalizable.

Comment: @bob.sacamento It depends on the distribution you draw from of course, but for most reasonable distributions (especially continuous ones), you'll find the probability is in fact zero. Actually, in the 2x2 case, a diagonalizable matrix with a degenerate eigenvalue is just a multiple of the identity! (No longer true in higher dimensions, again.)